# postgres select values from a table with an extra dependency

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I would like the next query for postgres:

```
SELECT name
    FROM Table1 as T1
    WHERE T1.id = ( 
          SELECT id 
          FROM Table2 AS T2
          WHERE T2.active=true)
```

So, I need to get all the values from the first table, whose `id` matches the ones set as `active` in another table.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How to correctly implement that query, as mine is failing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a sub query for this. Use a join. It will be a lot more efficient.

```
SELECT T1.name
FROM Table1 as T1
INNER JOIN Table2 as T2 ON T2.id = T1.id AND T2.active=true
```

Comment: If there is more than one record in `Table2` with the same `id` this will duplicate records in the resultset.

Comment: add `distinct(T1.name)` in that case. Still don't need a subquery.

Comment: It is a performance myth that is not true that a JOIN is more efficient - especially if you have to apply a `distinct` (which is not a function btw) afterwards to remove the excess rows that aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

The equality operator imposes that the subquery should return a single record. You want `IN` instead, which accepts a resultset:

```
SELECT T1.name
FROM Table1 as T1
WHERE T1.id IN (SELECT id FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T2.active)
```

This can also be expressed with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT T1.name
FROM Table1 as T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.id AND T2.active)
```

Note that in Postgres condition `T2.active = true` can be shortened `T2.active`.

For performance, you want an index on `Table2(id, active)` and another on `Table1(id)`.